# How to make this type of layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to make this type of layout.

like this:

[image]

I need this shadow effect, I tried enough but did not get it.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so you can be helped better

Answer (score 0):

Its called bottom bar. It is used for navigation of pages.

Learn More:
https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage

Useful Resource:
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that,you need to create custom shape for bottom navigation,to create bottom navigation see [Bottom Navigation](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/) then give shadow to selected option, for shadow check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26707332/4850591),

```
public class ThreeButtonsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_three_buttons);

        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.three_buttons_activity);

        BottomBar bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.three_buttons_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
                switch (itemId) {
                    case R.id.recent_item:
                        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Recent Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.favorite_item:
                        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Favorite Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.location_item:
                        Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Location Item Selected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        // Set the color for the active tab. Ignored on mobile when there are more than three tabs.
        bottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#C2185B");

        // Use the dark theme. Ignored on mobile when there are more than three tabs.
        //bottomBar.useDarkTheme(true);

        // Use custom text appearance in tab titles.
        //bottomBar.setTextAppearance(R.style.MyTextAppearance);

        // Use custom typeface that's located at the "/src/main/assets" directory. If using with
        // custom text appearance, set the text appearance first.
        //bottomBar.setTypeFace("MyFont.ttf");
    }
}
```